# The second method in controller doesn't work PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, controller

I have problem .Second method in controller does not to work .Output :`undefined variable item.` In construct method anything is work . I searched  in google about this item but nothing found    Please help me resolve this problem. Thanks advance.

Controller

```
require_once("model/Model.php");

class Controller
{   

    function __construct()
    {   

        $image = array();   
        $image = Model::selectAll();
        require_once("view/index.php"); 

    }

    public function actionCategory($param = 0)
    {       

        $item = Model::selectByName($param);
        require_once("view/index.php"); 

    }

}
```

Model

```
 class Model
{
    static public function selectAll()
    {


        $names = array("jhon" , "Hilary" , "Steven, "Jake");

        return $names;

    }

    static public function selectByName($param)
    {   

        $param = strval($param);

        $param = "Hilary";

        return $param;

    }
}
```

View

```
foreach($names as $key)
{
   print($key);
}

print($item);
```

Comment: Why don't you use the classic way to display views in CI ? https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: I have a task create mvc on clean php code without framework

Comment: You are missing a " after Steven